# Regarding IE9 execution with selenium webdriver

Tags: eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium

Friends i am trying to automate in IE9 using selenium webdriver but getting following error in eclipse log . Please help.

```
Internet Explorer is selected
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.27.0.0
Listening on port 5032
May 23, 2014 4:48:43 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
May 23, 2014 4:48:43 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

Comment: You need to remove any external added toolbar from your IE browser. And most probably your issue will be resolved.

Comment: @SathishD: These are not related to toolbars..

Answer (score 0):

Add this before creating a driver. This will avoid showing the port info.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver.silent","true");
```

You can safely ignore the INFO messages which is not actually an issue or error.

Details information on those INFO message are at http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/12/seeing-info-messages-in-log-does-not.html